# what's different @android:id/list @+id/android:list?

Tags: android

i see two listview xml code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
...
```

and

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
```

whats different between those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@+id/test` means you are creating an id named test in the namespace of
your application. You can refer to it using `@id/test`.

`@android:id/test`
means you are referring to an id defined in the android namespace.

Comment: i say " @+id/android:list " , not " @+id/list " . by the way , because of i have custom listview , so if i use @+id/list , IDE Comiler shows a error that says i have to use @android:id/list   !

Comment: in this example,you can see what i said about @+id/android:list
http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/android-changing-listview-background-colors

Answer (score 1):

Using the `+` tells Android to update the R.java file.

> The plus-symbol (+) means that this is a new resource name that must be created and added to our resources (in the R.java file).

Read all about it at [Android XML Layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html)